# how to convert string to timestamp using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df with column that contains the following format: `2020-04-20T03:18:07.000+0000`
I want to convert it to format that looks like this: `2020-04-20 03:18:07.000000`

This is what I did:

```
   def _to_timestamp(cls, col):
        """
        Convert a column of a dataframe from String to Timestamp if applicable
        :param col:     A Series object representing a column of a dataframe.
        """
        try:
            col = pd.to_datetime(col)
        except ValueError:
            print(
                "Could not convert field to timestamps: {0}".format(col.name)
            )
            return col

        converted = []
        for i in col:
            try:
                converted.append(i.fromisoformat())   <-- PROBLEM IS HERE
            except ValueError:
                converted.append(pd.np.NaN)
            except AttributeError:
                converted.append(pd.np.NaN)


cols =['originDate', 'destenationDate','caseTimestamp']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(
                lambda x: self._to_timestamp(x)
            )
```

The function gives me Nan for the columns
If I change `i.fromisoformat()` to `i.timestamp()` it works but it returns me UNIX Posix which is not what I need
What am I doing wrong here?

Error is:

> AttributeError: ("'Timestamp' object has no attribute
>   'fromisoformat'", 'occurred at index originDate')

Comment: What is your logic with the `_to_timestamp` function? And why is `2020-04-20` converted to `2020-04-26`?

Comment: Printing the error that it produces might give you a better clue.

Comment: @CodeDifferent it's just format example no intention to the actual values

Comment: @Keith added error

Comment: The `i` object is apparently a Timestamp object already. It doesn't have a `fromisoformat` method.  You then catch that error and append the `NaN`.  You are setting the NaN, not the function.

Comment: @Keith could be because `i` of `col ` is value after `col = pd.to_datetime(col)` so how can I set it to the proper format?

Comment: @Keith maybe to_datefime(col) should also be passed with format parameter?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to convert specific string object into a datetime object. You can convert it in this fashion:

```
from datetime import datetime
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'))
```

Comment: That doesn't sound very efficent

Comment: Do you already have it in the datetime format or is it in string format?

Comment: string. I want to change it to datetime